# All the ceiling light stopped working apart from 1

Tags: electrical

All of my lights in the ceiling have stopped working apart from 1, they are all on the same circuit breaker and thus has not tripped. When I check the wires there seems to be electricity everywhere.

When I put my testing pen towards the light bulbs there seems to be electricity there even when the switch is turned to off.

I a, just left with 1 working light in the apartment.

Any ideas?

Comment: Has anyone done any work around the non working lights?  Have you checked for any GFCI outlets that might control the lights?  Testing pens  are not good for trouble shooting problems, get a volt meter.

Comment: What kind of lights? If fluorescent, the (or one) ballast may be acting up.

Comment: You said "apartment"  In the USA that generally means you are renting, not always, but usually. If in the USA and you are renting, that's a landlord issue.  You are not allowed to do electrical work yourself in a rented apartment.   Contact your landlord and get them to fix it.

Comment: It's a first floor flat in the UK.  All the lights are on the same circuit. All off apart from 1 , seems to be electricity everywhere on the circuit. No florescent lights.